# XSLT: How to find the count of unique children of a node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML looks like this:

```
<foo>
    <bar name="a">
        <baz name="xyz">
            <time>2</time>
            <date>3</date>
        </baz>
    </bar>
    <bar name="b">
        <baz name="xyz">
            <time>2</time>
            <date>3</date>
        </baz>
    </bar>
    <bar name="c">
        <baz name="xyz">
            <time>2</time>
            <date>3</date>
        </baz>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

I am writing an XSL that needs to function like this: If all the `baz` children are same then `doSomething` else `doSomethingElse`. My current node is `foo`.

I am new to XSLT and I am aware of the conditionals in XSL. It looks something like this as of now:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">   
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="[My condition]"> 
        doSomething()
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        doSomethingElse()
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In the current example, it should `doSomething()` as all the `baz` elements are the same.

If I find out the number of unique `baz` elements, I can test whether it is equal to one. If it is, then I will `doSomething()` else `doSomethingElse()`

How should I implement this? What should `MyCondition` be?

PS: My XSL version is 1.0

Comment: Do you have the ability to use XSLT2? It'll make a *big* difference in this case.

Comment: Is that an open "the same" or a closed "the same"? Open would mean: There is no specification of what a `<baz>` may contain, but all of them must contain the same stuff anyway. Closed would mean: A `<baz>` has exactly N properties that I care about, and they must be the same across all of them. The former is very difficult, the latter is moderately difficult and depends on the number N.

Comment: @Flynn1179, Yes, I think I can use 2.0. I was using some of the code from W3Schools and they use 1.0. But I tried changing the version in <xsl:stylesheet version to 2.0 and it still works! So I assume, yes!

Comment: @Tomalak all the `baz` elements will have the same tags but might have different values.

Comment: So please write out an exact definition of what values must be considered. Without that, any answers will be guesswork. Also include the name and version of the XSLT processor in use.

Comment: @Tomalak For the purpose of illustration, lets assume that `baz` can only have `date` and `time`. The values may differ. XSLT version being used is 2.0 (I was using some of the code from W3Schools and they use 1.0. But I tried changing the version in <xsl:stylesheet version to 2.0 and it still works! So I assume, yes. )

Comment: Just look at your XSLT processor and tell the exact name and version. That's better than making assumptions.

Comment: I was gonna say, don't assume that. If in doubt, you can use `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />` to get the version of XSL you have available.

Comment: @Tomalak My XSL version is 1.0

Comment: @Flynn1179 My XSL version is 1.0. Thanks for that trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If all the `baz` children are same then `doSomething` else
>   `doSomethingElse`. My current node is `foo`.

This is confusing because:

- `baz` are not children of `foo`;
- your title says "*find the count of unique children*" - but it is not
  necessary to find it in order to know if they are same.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:variable name="first-baz" select="(bar/baz)[1]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="bar/baz[date!=$first-baz/date or time!=$first-baz/time]">
            <!-- THEY ARE NOT ALL SAME -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- THEY ARE ALL SAME -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes that every `baz` has a `date` and a `time`. Otherwise you need to test for `not(date=$first-baz/date)` etc.

See also:
http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

---

### Added:

> Now, assuming all the `bar/baz` elements have the same tags (not
>   necessarily `date` and `time` but say `a`, `b` and `c`), what would be
>   the test attribute for that case?

This makes it significantly more complex. Still  you could construct a key:

```
<xsl:key name="first-baz" match="foo/bar[1]/baz[1]/*" use="name()" />
```

then make your test:

```
<xsl:when test="bar/baz/*[. != key('first-baz', name())]">
```

This returns true if any child of `baz` exists whose string-value is different from an equally named node that is child of the first `baz`.

Note that the key, as defined here, is document-wide. If you want to restrict the test to the current `foo` ancestor, then you must include its id in the key.

Comment: You don't need to loop through all the `baz` children to check if each of them are equal/unequal to the first one?

Comment: No, because the XPath in the `test` attribute just checks for the existence of at least one that isn't equal. If you've found one, you don't need to 'loop' through any more.

Comment: @Core_Dumped The XSLT processor does all the necessary looping - you only need to specify the condition.

Comment: I see!. Very interesting! Thanks for the answer and clarifications.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Now, assuming all the `bar/baz` elements have the same tags (not necessarily `date` and `time` but say `a`, `b` and `c`), what would be the test attribute for that case? Can I somehow loop in all the children of each `bar/baz` and do this value check without knowing the actual tags?

Comment: Very nice variable usage, plus one.

Comment: @Core_Dumped I have added the answer to my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a generic way then you are really stretching the capability of XSLT 1.0 beyond its design limits. But it can be done.

Write a named template called deep-equal that takes two elements as its arguments and returns a string containing the character "F" if and only if they are not equal (for your purposes).

It might look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="deep-equal">
  <xsl:param name="a"/>
  <xsl:param name="b"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name(a) != local-name(b)">F</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="namespace-uri(a) != namespace-uri(b)">F</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(a) != normalize-space(b)">F</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="count(a/*) != count(b/*)">F</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="diffs">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="deep-equal">
            <xsl:with-param name="a" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="b" select="$b/*[$position]"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Apply this to all relevant pairs of elements:

```
    <xsl:variable name="comparison">
      <xsl:for-each select="baz[position() &gt;= 2]">
       <xsl:call-template name="deep-equal">
         <xsl:with-param name="a" select="../baz[1]"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="b" select="."/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Test if the result contains an "F":

```
<xsl:if test="contains($comparison, 'F')">...</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I've come back to this following another question. This doesn't really work, does it? I mean, if it fails the 4 tests, it opens a variable and writes something into it - but that variable remains out-of-scope for any practical purpose. Even if I remove the variable, and add the missing $ in the param references, and change `baz[position() &gt;= 2]` to `bar[position() &gt;= 1]`, I still can't get it to work even in the simplest scenario: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGS - not to mention in a truly generic way, that would not depend on the context of the calling template.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure it can be done, but I'm not strongly motivated to write XSLT 1.0 code that proves it.

Comment: I am sure it can be done too - but I don't see how it can be done the way you have outlined.